# Best way to "match" an array of polygon vertices to another?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, matching, vertices

I have an array of coordinates making up one 2D polygon. The coordinates are in order and determines how the polygon is drawn.

I have a similar array of coordinates for another 2D polygon that has more vertices than the first.

Assume that both polygons are centered on top of each other in 2D space.

How can I find which vertices from the smaller shape "match up" to the larger shape, while keeping the order of the polygons consistent? A match is based off of how close a vertex is from one polygon to the next.

```
0____________1
|------------|
|------------|
|------------|
3____________2

------0---------
-----/-\--------
---1/---\____6--
---|----7----|--
---|------4__|--
---|-------\-5--
---2________3---

EX solution:
0 : Null
1 : 0
2 : 3
3 : 2
4 : Null
5 : Null
6 : 1
7 : Null
```

I've been struggling with this problem for over a week now, and could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: To me, this doesn't seem to be a very well defined problem, because "match up" could mean different things in different situations (although it's clear in the example you gave that 1-2-3-6 is most like the 0-1-2-3 of your first shape).  Perhaps it would help if you specify what the results of the match-up will be used for.

Comment: The matches are used to determine how one polygon will morph from one to the next, and which vertices will be moved to form the new shape. A match should be determined by distance. Unfortunately you can't just match them up to the closest distances, otherwise it may break ordering.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but your problem seems similar to gesture/handwriting recognition http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/recognition-of-handwritten-gestures-r2039. That said, matching each point of the first polygon to the closest one in the second only leaves point 2 to be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be expressed as trying to find a minimum-cost maximum matching between the vertices in the first polygon and the vertices in the second polygon, with the added requirement of no intersecting edges.

This paper should be helpful: http://home.deib.polimi.it/malucell/papers/NCM.pdf